# Вывод результата во время работы скрипта

Tags: php

Добрый день есть скрипт время выполнение которого больше часа как сделать чтобы видеть результат выполнения скрипта во время работы а не после окончания работы скрипта функция **flush()** не помогает, реально ли это реализовать только с помощью php

Comment: 21 вопрос задан. 26% принятых, что примерно 5,5 ответов.

Как итог. Прочитай все свои вопросы, прими правильные ответы. А вот потом кто-нибудь тебе и ответит на новый вопрос.

Это что-то вроде уважения на форуме. Раз ты не удосуживаешься принять ответ, то на твой вопрос так же никто не удосужится ответить.

Comment: а как принимать ответ? если имеете в виду выбирать правильный ответ то я выбираю его

Comment: Ну вот я привел пример из 21 вопроса всего 5 принято.

Comment: Смотрите здесь:  
http://hashcode.ru/questions/93191#93267

Answer (score 2):

Консоль или вэб?

В первом случае у меня все выводится в режиме реального времени,
во втором случае - браузер ждет полной загрузки страницы, в этом случае только писать в файл.

Comment: скрипт будет запущен в браузере

Comment: тогда лучше в файл писать... подругому никак скорее всего не получится...

судя по документации `flush()` в вашем случае не работает изза того, что в апаче включен и работает модуль mod_gzip

> Серверные модули для Apache, такие как mod_gzip, могут сами выполнять буферизацию, поэтому flush() не приводит к немедленной передаче данных клиенту.

без него `flush()` должен работать, его можно отключить через `.htaccess` поидее